# Html header not showing properly on mobile

Tags: html, css, github, mobile

I recently edited an html code to do my portfolio and host it on GitHub pages. Howver, I am facing a problem when opening the site on my mobile where the header isn't showing fully. I attached a picture illustrating the problem. I would appreciate any help since I have no prior experience in html/css. GitHub Link: https://github.com/georgeselkassouf/portfolio

[image]`

```
    <!-- Wrapper -->
        <div id="wrapper">

            <!-- Header -->
                <header id="header">
                    <h1>Georges Elkassouf</h1>
                        <p>Data Analyst
                </header>
```

`

Comment: I suggest to read up on `Media Queries` and then find the code that is responsible for the CSS of the `<header>` when the viewport changes width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use media queries on the elements you want to make responsive

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries